# Running CGI outside of cgi-bin. Good idea?

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

I'm considering moving from PHP to Python (for personal projects), and I really don't like seeing /cgi-bin/ in my URL.

I got the Python to execute outside of cgi-bin, but I just wanted to make sure there were no possible security issues that could pop up, and that there were no major impacts on the speed.

So are there any major issues I need to be aware of?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why aren't you using `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: Never heard of it, and I doubt my host has it, unless it's a _very_ common module.

Comment: "I doubt my host has it,"  Bad assumption.  Get proof before wasting too much time on a more complex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being as how it's nominally just a URL, there aren't any impacts on speed per-se. However, it is standard practice, just like it's standard practice to make the entry page to a website index.html, but it's not required by any stretch (as evidenced by default.aspx, home.php, etc)

I would change it as a security through obscurity reference myself, were I inclined to change those things on my system.

While you won't incur any Apache security issues, there may be issues with server-side code or hard-coded modules that don't query for path, and assume code is running from cgi-bin ... just something to consider.